# SPHttpClients vs AadHttpClient vs MsGrpahclient

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-graph, graph-api, sphttpclient

When developing SPFx we are left with many technologies to be used. mainly i am trying to understand when to use each

SPHttpClients vs AadHttpClient vs MsGrpahclient

now i know  the SPHttpClient can be used to integrate with SharePoint but since it uses SharePoint REST API so it is considered as legacy approach, since Microsoft is not adding any new features to SharePoint rest api and it is replacing it by graph api.

so i have these 2 questions:-

1. If we want to perform CRUD operations to SharePoint lists using non-legacy approach, which class we need to use?
2. also if we want to integrate with Graph which class we need to use AadHttpClient vs MsGrpahclient? and why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, the vast majority of developers use the SharePoint REST API, rather than Microsoft Graph, to interact with SharePoint in SPFx code. When using the REST API, there's no need to authenticate with Azure AD to get a token and no need to request API permissions, all of that is handled for you by SharePoint.

Also, if you weren't aware, it's possible to use the REST API to call the Microsoft Graph site, list, and file endpoints. See [SharePoint REST operations via the Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698) for more information.

Finally, the MSGraphClient is specifically designed to call Microsoft Graph while the AadHttpClient is designed to call any API secured by Azure AD. You can use either client object to call Microsoft Graph, but I think it makes most sense to use the one specifically designed for that purpose.

Comment: so if i get your reply correctly then both the MSGraphClient and AddHttpClient can be used to call sharePoint and Graph API ?

Comment: MSGraphClient can only be used to call Microsoft Graph. That is, it can only call endpoints that start with "https://graph.microsoft.com". AddHttpClient can call any service that is secured by Azure AD. That means you could call Microsoft Graph using the AddHttpClient. SPHttpClient can only be used to call the SharePoint REST API. That is, it can only call endpoints that start with a SharePoint site URL (e.g. "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/demo".

Comment: so i can NOT use MSGraphClient or AddHttpClient to call SharePoint endpoints? or i can use AadHttpClient to call SharePoint endpoints?